# Which glasses for stereoscopy java program?

Tags: java, java-3d, stereoscopy

I am trying to develop a 3D program in Java, which would use stereoscopy. I'm quite new in this domain, and don't know exactly how everything works. After some research, I've heard of **NVIDIA 3D Vision** and **Java3D**.

What do I need to easily display 3D images in a Java program? Is it possible only using Java3D API and buying some specific glasses, or do I need to buy a system like **NVIDIA 3D Vision**? Does it exist for other systems, like open-source? Do you have links for this glasses?

Answer (score 3):

There are three popular stereoscopy systems: color anaglyph (e.g red & blue), polarization system and shutter system.

Using java with color anaglyph could be done by duplicating models with different colors and rotate/move them slightly apart. End client need to wear two color glases to see 3D but the quality is low.
Higher quality could be obtained by using passive polarization system: stereoscopic monitor and stereoscopic glasses (like glasses in IMAX) or active shutter system (Nvidia 3D, uses special monitor and glasses also), but the price is high.

Java 3D is long dead. New 2D&3D library from Oracle is JavaFX 2.0. There are also open-source 3D game engines written in Java.

To use Nvidia 3D Vision you need special monitor and glasses. Some games use it to be seen 3D and I think thats a good starting point to google them. Only programme I know that uses Nvidia 3D vision is 3Ds Max 2012+.